# Confusion in solving a problem related to elasticity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity

This the question given in my textbook:

> A thin, uniform rod of length $l$ is rotated with constant angular speed $\omega$ about an axis passing through it's one end and perpendicular to one end of the rod.
> Find the increase in the length.
> $[$ Density of material is $d$ and Young's modulus is $Y$ $]$

$\bf{Solution}$

$-dT = dm\omega^2x$

$-\int_{0}^{T(x)} dT $ = $\int_{L}^{x} \frac{M}{L}dx\omega^2x$
]

$T(x) = \frac{dA\omega^2L^2}{2}(1 - \frac{x^2}{L^2})$

$A=$ area of cross section of the rod, which is constant for the rod

For the element:

$\frac{T(x)}{A} = Y\frac{dl}{dx}$

or,

$dl = \frac{T(x)dx}{AY} = \frac{d\omega^2L^2}{2Y}(1 - \frac{x^2}{L^2})$

I don't understand this step $\frac{T(x)}{A} = Y\frac{dl}{dx}$. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That equation is basically equating Young's modulus to stress by strain ratio, i.e.

$$Y=\frac{T/A}{\Delta l/l}$$

- As the tension is a function of $x$ on the rod, it is denoted as $T(x)$.
- Area of cross section is $A$.
- $\Delta l$, the change in length is denoted by $dl$.
- $l$, the length under consideration is $dx$. Note that the textbook has considered an  - infinitesimal length because tension $T(x)$ is not constant throughout the length of the rod. But we can assume it to be constant for an infinitesimally small length $dx$.

Also note that $dl$ is the change in length of *only* the $dx$ part, and not the whole rod.

Then you get your equation
$$Y\frac{dl}{dx}=\frac {T(x)}A$$
Which gives the integral
$$\int dl = \int_{x=0}^{x=l} \frac{T(x)dx}{YA}$$

You put limits as $x=0$ to $x=l$ because $x$ varies from $0\to l$. The LHS gives you $\Delta l$ which is the *total* increment in length of the *whole* rod.